# Mint new position fails uniswap v3

Tags: mint, uniswapv3

I am using the code example of uniswap to mint a new position and add deposit: https://github.com/Uniswap/docs/blob/main/examples/smart-contracts/LiquidityExamples.sol

Below is my code:

```
/// @notice Calls the mint function defined in periphery, mints the same amount of each token.
/// For this example we are providing 1000 DAI and 1000 USDC in liquidity
/// @return tokenId The id of the newly minted ERC721
/// @return liquidity The amount of liquidity for the position
/// @return amount0 The amount of token0
/// @return amount1 The amount of token1
function mintNewPosition(uint256 _amount0, uint256 _amount1)
    external
    returns (
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint128 liquidity,
        uint256 amount0,
        uint256 amount1
    )
{
    // For this example, we will provide equal amounts of liquidity in both assets.
    // Providing liquidity in both assets means liquidity will be earning fees and is considered in-range.
    uint256 amount0ToMint = _amount0;
    uint256 amount1ToMint = _amount1;

    // transfer tokens to contract
    TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(DAI, msg.sender, address(this), amount0ToMint);
    TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(USDC, msg.sender, address(this), amount1ToMint);

    // Approve the position manager
    TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), amount0ToMint);
    TransferHelper.safeApprove(USDC, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), amount1ToMint);
    // int24 _tickLower = -887272;
    // int24 _tickUpper = -_tickLower;
    int24 tickSpacing = 60;
    // _tickLower = _tickLower<0?-(-_tickLower/tickSpacing*tickSpacing):_tickLower/tickSpacing*tickSpacing;

    // _tickUpper=_tickUpper<0?-(-_tickUpper/tickSpacing*tickSpacing):_tickUpper/tickSpacing*tickSpacing;



    INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams memory params =
        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
            token0: DAI,
            token1: USDC,
            fee: poolFee,
            tickLower: 269392 - tickSpacing*2,
            tickUpper: 269392 + tickSpacing*2,
            amount0Desired: amount0ToMint,
            amount1Desired: amount1ToMint,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp
        });

    // // Note that the pool defined by DAI/USDC and fee tier 0.3% must already be created and initialized in order to mint
    (tokenId, liquidity, amount0, amount1) = nonfungiblePositionManager.mint(params);

    // Create a deposit
    _createDeposit(msg.sender, tokenId);

    // Remove allowance and refund in both assets.
    if (amount0 < amount0ToMint) {
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), 0);
        uint256 refund0 = amount0ToMint - amount0;
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(DAI, msg.sender, refund0);
    }

    if (amount1 < amount1ToMint) {
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(USDC, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), 0);
        uint256 refund1 = amount1ToMint - amount1;
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(USDC, msg.sender, refund1);
    }
}
```

The function fails when it calls the mint() function of nonfungiblePositionManager.

Can someone comments what could be the cause?

Note:
I have approved enough tokens of both type already.